# Dynamically Run custom tool in Entity framework edmx, context.tt and model.tt

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, msbuild, teamcity, web-deployment

I am running msbuild on a build server outside visual studio IDE programmatically. How can I run custom tool on model.tt and context.tt when running msbuild programmatically.

Comment: T4 templates are designed to run at design-time, not build-time.  The output files should be up-to-date before you build, either in VS or from the command-line.  In the case of the old EF Database First, each time you update the EDMX, the templates run and the output files are updated.

Comment: Hi friend, you can try to use `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating; ... Engine engine = new Engine();string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(templateString, host);`. More info you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/processing-text-templates-by-using-a-custom-host?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response the problem is that the build is running on the build server and we don’t check in generated template classes. So the intention is to run custom tooling outside visual studio.

Comment: The other possibility is running custom tool itself from command line before running build